# Conditionally pull value from one of two different fields

Tags: jq

I'm new to jq and am attempting to grab a few fields from a json response. The field of note is the "key" field under the "roles" subsection. Here is an example of the response format:

```
{
  "took": 755,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10000,
      "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "user_data": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "user1",
          "doc_count": 872721,
          "response_status": {
            "buckets": {
              "success": {
                "from": 200,
                "to": 300,
                "doc_count": 872709,
                "roles": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "key": "example-role",
                      "doc_count": 872709
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "failure": {
                "from": 400,
                "to": 500,
                "doc_count": 0,
                "roles": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": []
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "user2",
          "doc_count": 2286,
          "response_status": {
            "buckets": {
              "success": {
                "from": 200,
                "to": 300,
                "doc_count": 2285,
                "roles": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 2285,
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "key": "example-role",
                      "doc_count": 2285
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "failure": {
                "from": 400,
                "to": 500,
                "doc_count": 1,
                "roles": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 1,
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "key": "example-role",
                      "doc_count": 1
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "user4",
          "doc_count": 872721,
          "response_status": {
            "buckets": {
              "success": {
                "from": 200,
                "to": 300,
                "doc_count": 872709,
                "roles": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": []
                }
              },
              "failure": {
                "from": 400,
                "to": 500,
                "doc_count": 0,
                "roles": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": []
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "user4",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "response_status": {
            "buckets": {
              "success": {
                "from": 200,
                "to": 300,
                "doc_count": 0,
                "roles": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": []
                }
              },
              "failure": {
                "from": 400,
                "to": 500,
                "doc_count": 1,
                "roles": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "key": "example-role",
                      "doc_count": 1
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To explain the end goal, I'm gathering aggregate data on http success/failures by user and user role. Not all users have roles but I still want data for those users, which is why the query is structured this way.

My question is how to pull the role of a user, or null if they have no roles. There are 3 clear cases in the example above: a user with either successes and no failures or vice versa that has a role, a user with both that has a role, and a user that has no roles. I've managed to write this jq command in order to filter which users do/don't have roles:

```
.aggregations|.user_data|.buckets[]|.response_status|.buckets|map(.roles|.buckets|map(has("key")))|flatten|any
```

Which for this data returns this:

```
true
true
false
true
```

How do I get from this to returning the role itself if true, or null if false so that for this example I would return:

```
"example-role"
"example-role"
null
"example-role"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the desired output

Comment: @0stone0 I've edited the question to include the desired output for the example.

Comment: So you only want to check those from the `success` key?

Comment: @0stone0 No, I've added a fourth example to explicitly state all cases. I'd like to check the failure key as well so that if the success key is null I don't miss the role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should generate expected output :

```
.aggregations.user_data.buckets[]
|.response_status.buckets
|map(.roles.buckets|map(select(has("key")).key))
|flatten
|first
```

Version without `select`

```
.aggregations.user_data.buckets[]
|.response_status.buckets
|map(.roles.buckets|map(.key // empty))
|flatten|first
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that there must need to be a select in there somewhere but couldn't quite figure it out. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `first/1` which evaluates to the first item of the stream provided. This way, branches can already be cut after finding the first occurrence, and there's no need to further process (`flatten/0`) and extract (`first/0`) from a fully computed structure.

```bash
.aggregations.user_data.buckets[].response_status.buckets
| first(.[].roles.buckets[].key, null)
```

```json
"example-role"
"example-role"
null
"example-role"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rlIn6W7Po60)